# How to get latest RStudio version

Tags: r, bash, xpath, rstudio

I am struggling with writing a script that would somehow scrape the `https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/` for the number of the latest RStudio version, download it and install it.

Since I am an R programmer, I started to write an R script using `rvest` package. I managed to scrape the download link for the RStudio server, but I still cannot get the RStudio itself.

Here is the R code for getting a download link for the 64bit RStudio-server for Ubuntu.

```
if(!require('stringr')) install.packages('stringr', Ncpus=8, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
if(!require('rvest')) install.packages('rvest', Ncpus=8, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')

xpath<-'//code[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 3) and parent::*)]'
url<-'https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/'
thepage<-xml2::read_html(url)
the_links_html <- rvest::html_nodes(thepage,xpath=xpath)
the_links <- rvest::html_text(the_links_html)
the_link <- the_links[stringr::str_detect(the_links, '-amd64\\\\.deb')]
the_r_uri<-stringr::str_match(the_link, 'https://.*$')
cat(the_r_uri)
```

Unfortunately, the RStudio desktop download page has completely different layout, and I the same approach doesn't work here.

Can someone help me with this? I can't believe, that all the data scientist in the world manually upgrade their RStudio!

---

There is an even simpler version of the script, that reads the version of the RStudio-server. Bash version:

```
RSTUDIO_LATEST=$(wget --no-check-certificate -qO- https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/current.ver)
```

or R version:

```
scan('https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/current.ver', what = character(0))
```

But the version of the RStudio-desktop still eludes me.

Comment: Does R Studio not check itself for updates when you run it?

Comment: Yes it does, a configurable option - but that's not what's being asked for here.

Comment: @mdsumner yes, but RStudio is open source, so the solution is there.

Comment: right, it's obvious now you explain it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query RStudio's `check_for_update` with a version string you'll get back the update version and the URL of where to get it from:

https://www.rstudio.org/links/check_for_update?version=1.0.0

> update-version=1.0.153&update-url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rstudio.com%2Fproducts%2Frstudio%2Fdownload%2F&update-message=RStudio%201.0.153%20is%20now%20available%20%28you%27re%20using%201.0.0%29&update-urgent=0

See here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/54cd3abcfc58837b433464c793fe9b03a87f0bb4/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionUpdates.R

If you really want to scrape it from the download page then I'd get the `href` of the `<a>` in the first `<td>` of the first `<table>` of class "downloads", and then parse out the three dot-separated numbers between "RStudio-" and ".exe". RStudio release versions over all platforms so getting it from the Windows download should be sufficient.

```
> url = "https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/"
> thepage<-xml2::read_html(url)
> html_node(thepage, ".downloads td a") %>% html_attr("href")
[1] "https://download1.rstudio.org/RStudio-1.0.153.exe"
```

Comment: This is the one-liner that I settled for: `stringr::str_match(scan("https://www.rstudio.org/links/check_for_update?version=1.0.0", what = character(0)), '^[^=]+=([^\\&]+)\\&.*')[[2]]`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can get the latest stable version number from the url http://download1.rstudio.org/current.ver and it is more up to date (for some unknown reason), at least at the time of writing this answer.

`$ curl -s http://download1.rstudio.org/current.ver
1.1.447`

`$ curl -s https://www.rstudio.org/links/check_for_update?version=1.0.0 | grep -oEi 'update-version=([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
1.1.423`

Found that here: https://github.com/yutannihilation/ansible-playbook-r/blob/master/tasks/install-rstudio-server.yml

Answer (score 1):

There's a nearly-solution here:

https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio-daily/~/dockerfile/

In this script, which scrapes for the latest builds:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocker-org/rstudio-daily/master/latest.R

You'll want to modify that script to be more strict about what it accepts, i.e. I would want this one `rstudio-server-1.1.355-amd64.deb` and not the `stretch` variant.

(But you can modify it to target the kind of build you want anyway, this is the daily builds, RStudio Server for Ubuntu.)

Comment: Thank you. The immidiate link you put is for the daily build of the RStudio (server), but that could be easily fixed. For the stable RStudio (server) they use `RSTUDIO_LATEST=$(wget --no-check-certificate -qO- https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-server/current.ver)`

Comment: The real problem with your proposal is that the `rocker` servs only the RStudio-server, because they use docker containers and never bother to encapsulate the GUI application. And I already have a web scraping script to read the current RStudio-server version.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, here is my ultimate RServer-desktop-on-Ubuntu update script. It installs `RStudio-desktop` 64bit and then, if `Fira Console` font is available, applies a patch from https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/RStudio-instructions for the RStudio, so the ligatures start working.

```
#!/bin/bash
if dpkg -s rstudio >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    ver=$(apt show rstudio | grep Version)
    pattern='^Version: ([0-9.]+)\s*$'
    if [[ $ver =~ $pattern ]]; then
        ourversion=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        netversion=$(Rscript -e 'cat(stringr::str_match(scan("https://www.rstudio.org/links/check_for_update?version=1.0.0", what = character(0), quiet=TRUE), "^[^=]+=([^\\&]+)\\&.*")[[2]])')
        if [[ $ourversion != $netversion ]]; then
            RSTUDIO_URI=$(Rscript /tmp/get_rstudio_uri.R)
        fi
        tee /tmp/get_rstudio_uri.R <<EOF
if(!require('rvest')) install.packages('rvest', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
xpath='.downloads:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(5) a'
url = "https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/"
thepage<-xml2::read_html(url)
cat(html_node(thepage, xpath) %>% html_attr("href"))
EOF
        RSTUDIO_URI=$(Rscript /tmp/get_rstudio_uri.R)

        wget -c --output-document /tmp/rstudio.deb $RSTUDIO_URI 
        sudo dpkg -i /tmp/rstudio.deb
        rm /tmp/rstudio.deb
        rm /tmp/get_rstudio_uri.R

        if fc-list |grep -q FiraCode; then
            if !grep -q "text-rendering:" /usr/lib/rstudio/www/index.htm; then
                sudo sed -i '/<head>/a<style>*{text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}<\/style>' /usr/lib/rstudio/www/index.htm
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
```